# My SearchActivity does not show users while searching them

Tags: java, android, database, firebase

My SearchActivity does not show users. There is no errors shown, but there must be something wrong between searchForMatch and updateUsersList, because the last log which is showing in logcat is (TAG, "searchForMatch: searching for a match: " + keyword); I think there must be something wrong in that section of code but I do not know what:( Maybe something is wrong with Firebase?? Please help.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx;
import com.stek.ca_ltd.memestackupdating.Profile.ProfileActivity;
import com.stek.ca_ltd.memestackupdating.R;
import com.stek.ca_ltd.memestackupdating.Utils.BottomNavigationViewHelper;
import com.stek.ca_ltd.memestackupdating.Utils.UserListAdapter;
import com.stek.ca_ltd.memestackupdating.models.User;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;


/**
 * Created by User on 5/28/2017.
 */
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private static final String TAG = "SearchActivity";
    private static final int ACTIVITY_NUM = 1;

    private Context mContext = SearchActivity.this;

    //widgets
    private EditText mSearchParam;
    private ListView mListView;

    //vars
    private List<User> mUserList;
    private UserListAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        mSearchParam = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: started.");

        hideSoftKeyboard();
        setupBottomNavigationView();
        initTextListener();
    }

    private void initTextListener(){
        Log.d(TAG, "initTextListener: initializing");

        mUserList = new ArrayList<>();

        mSearchParam.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                String text = mSearchParam.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                searchForMatch(text);
            }
        });
    }

    private void searchForMatch(String keyword){
        Log.d(TAG, "searchForMatch: searching for a match: " + keyword);
        mUserList.clear();
        //update the users list view
        if(keyword.length() ==0){

        }else{
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            Query query = reference.child(getString(R.string.dbname_users))
                    .orderByChild(getString(R.string.field_username)).equalTo(keyword);
            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot :  dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: found user:" + singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class).toString());

                        mUserList.add(singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class));
                        //update the users list view
                        updateUsersList();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void updateUsersList(){
        Log.d(TAG, "updateUsersList: updating users list");

        mAdapter = new UserListAdapter(SearchActivity.this, R.layout.layout_user_listitem, mUserList);

        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: selected user: " + mUserList.get(position).toString());

                //navigate to profile activity
                Intent intent =  new Intent(SearchActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.calling_activity), getString(R.string.search_activity));
                intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.intent_user), mUserList.get(position));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }


    private void hideSoftKeyboard(){
        if(getCurrentFocus() != null){
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }


    /**
     * BottomNavigationView setup
     */
    private void setupBottomNavigationView(){
        Log.d(TAG, "setupBottomNavigationView: setting up BottomNavigationView");
        BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationViewEx = (BottomNavigationViewEx) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavViewBar);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.setupBottomNavigationView(bottomNavigationViewEx);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.enableNavigation(mContext, this,bottomNavigationViewEx);
        Menu menu = bottomNavigationViewEx.getMenu();
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(ACTIVITY_NUM);
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

And UserListAdapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.LayoutRes;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.stek.ca_ltd.memestackupdating.R;
import com.stek.ca_ltd.memestackupdating.models.User;
import com.stek.ca_ltd.memestackupdating.models.UserAccountSettings;

import java.util.List;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

/**
 * Created by User on 9/17/2017.
 */
public class UserListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User>{

    private static final String TAG = "UserListAdapter";


    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<User> mUsers = null;
    private int layoutResource;
    private Context mContext;

    public UserListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull List<User> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        mContext = context;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        layoutResource = resource;
        this.mUsers = objects;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder{
        TextView username, email;
        CircleImageView profileImage;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {


        final ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(layoutResource, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.username = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            holder.email = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.email);
            holder.profileImage = (CircleImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.username.setText(mUsers.get(position).getUsername());
        holder.email.setText(getItem(position).getEmail());

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query = reference.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_user_account_settings))
                .orderByChild(mContext.getString(R.string.field_user_id))
                .equalTo(getItem(position).getUser_id());
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: found user: " +
                            singleSnapshot.getValue(UserAccountSettings.class).toString());

                    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

                    imageLoader.displayImage(singleSnapshot.getValue(UserAccountSettings.class).getProfile_photo(),
                            holder.profileImage);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you took some wrong steps in your activity. you are initializing adapter multiple times and also you clear your user arraylist if the serach string is empty. My Below code may help you.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx;
import com.stek.ca_ltd.memestackupdating.Profile.ProfileActivity;
import com.stek.ca_ltd.memestackupdating.R;
import com.stek.ca_ltd.memestackupdating.Utils.BottomNavigationViewHelper;
import com.stek.ca_ltd.memestackupdating.Utils.UserListAdapter;
import com.stek.ca_ltd.memestackupdating.models.User;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;


public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private static final String TAG = "SearchActivity";
    private static final int ACTIVITY_NUM = 1;

    private Context mContext = SearchActivity.this;

    //widgets
    private EditText mSearchParam;
    private ListView mListView;

    //vars
    private List<User> mUserList;
    private List<User> mUserListTemp;
    private UserListAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        mSearchParam = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: started.");

        mUserList = new ArrayList<>();
        mUserListTemp = new ArrayList<>();

        mAdapter = new UserListAdapter(SearchActivity.this, R.layout.layout_user_listitem, mUserList);

        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        hideSoftKeyboard();
        setupBottomNavigationView();
        initTextListener();

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: selected user: " + mUserList.get(position).toString());

                //navigate to profile activity
                Intent intent =  new Intent(SearchActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.calling_activity), getString(R.string.search_activity));
                intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.intent_user), mUserList.get(position));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }

    private void initTextListener(){
        Log.d(TAG, "initTextListener: initializing");


        mSearchParam.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                String text = mSearchParam.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                searchForMatch(text);
            }
        });
    }

    private void searchForMatch(String keyword){
        Log.d(TAG, "searchForMatch: searching for a match: " + keyword);

        //update the users list view
        if(keyword.length() ==0){

        }else{
            mUserListTemp.clear();
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            Query query = reference.child(getString(R.string.dbname_users))
                    .orderByChild(getString(R.string.field_username)).equalTo(keyword);
            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot :  dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: found user:" + singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class).toString());

                        mUserListTemp.add(singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class));
                        //update the users list view

                    }

                    updateUsersList();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void updateUsersList(){
        Log.d(TAG, "updateUsersList: updating users list");

        if(mUserListTemp.size()>0)
        {
            mUserList.clear();
            mUserList.addAll(mUserListTemp);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }


    private void hideSoftKeyboard(){
        if(getCurrentFocus() != null){
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }


    /**
     * BottomNavigationView setup
     */
    private void setupBottomNavigationView(){
        Log.d(TAG, "setupBottomNavigationView: setting up BottomNavigationView");
        BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationViewEx = (BottomNavigationViewEx) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavViewBar);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.setupBottomNavigationView(bottomNavigationViewEx);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.enableNavigation(mContext, this,bottomNavigationViewEx);
        Menu menu = bottomNavigationViewEx.getMenu();
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(ACTIVITY_NUM);
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Crash occured caused by error " Unable to start activity ComponentInfo   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference"

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. Please try ones more.

Comment: Still not working. I will sent my UserListAdapter.java so you can look at it:)

Comment: Great Job. Sorry for late response. Where was the problem?

Comment: In not removing the toLowercase(); which I set 2 months ago to do some other stuff and I forgot about it. It searched only lowercase users